# Using pygame with tkinter in Python, how do I pause and unpause with the same button?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, pygame

Pygame is an extension you download that offers built in functions. I'm currently working on a song player, and have a button that pauses the song and unpauses the song. How can I combine these two buttons so that I click once and it pauses and then click again and it unpauses etc? I have two functions right now that needs to be made into one, as they will be assigned to one button..

This is the code I have that needs to be changed:

```
def pausesong():
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()

def unpausesong():
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#resume song #pause the song
pause=False
a=0 #for testing
def pausesong():
    global index,a
    global pause
    a=a+1
    #print(pause,a)
    if pause == False:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        pause = True
        print(pause,a)

    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        pause = False
        print(pause,a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with pygame, but a simple approach would be to add a flag variable that you can check.

```
def pausesong():
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    paused = True

def unpausesong():
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    paused = False
```

And then in your button event...

```
if paused:
    unpausesong()
else:
    pausesong()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def play_pause():
    paused = not paused
    if paused: pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    else: pygame.mixer.music.pause()
```